# I2C bus bad state after shutdown Raspberry-Arduino

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, driver, raspbian, i2c

I'm writing a kernel module, for a raspberry, that signals to an arduino on the i2c bus that is turning/turned off. For now it only writes a simple on/off byte that turns on and off a led on the arduino. I wrote a simple python script to test if it can establish a connection and it works, i wrote the module and on load/unload it works perfectly, but on shutdown i'm using `pm_power_off` function to call a write on the bus, while the raspberry starts correctly the handshake sending the address of the arduino after the ACK the bus is left in a bad state. Here is the logic analyzer output:

[bus state, i tried tried a blinking sequence on poweroff](https://preview.redd.it/qfp5v3xyy22c1.png?width=577&format=png&auto=webp&s=0292486bc238a3b83abc47697ced0c8c42da3d6c)

[This is the first send before the bus goes on deadlock](https://preview.redd.it/bkoaifr1z22c1.png?width=866&format=png&auto=webp&s=2efac5dde06aac11fc54703bba8a755f2e87737e)

[some of the packets return a NACK but its the bad sampling](https://preview.redd.it/46p9sdr2z22c1.png?width=1105&format=png&auto=webp&s=024f7782e86a81bfff5cc4034a94d9934efe0341)

[this is the python script/module load/unload](https://preview.redd.it/q8979156z22c1.png?width=1382&format=png&auto=webp&s=777411916cde47dc1ee41de5b686346bcd3c63c0)

So i tried to write multiple times on poweroff to see if the module was still loaded, and it seems it is? It is sending the write requests to the correct address so the module is loaded and even the i2c module if the system can write on the lines. So why is going in a inconsistent state?

Also i saw that `pm_poweroff_prepare` exists but has been removed in the latest kernels

PS: sry for the bad sampling rate (250MHz) that somethimes duplicates a bit, i tried 200 for the perfect rate and the bus shows the same outputs but it dosent sample somethimes one longer bit of one clock.
The Boards i'm using: Arduino Uno for the slave, Raspberry pi 3b+ ( for testing, final board will be a zero 2w) with raspbian lite 64bit kernel 6.1.21

Source code: https://github.com/ilnerdchuck/GBA-SPi/tree/RPi-i2c-pw-Driver/Raspberry/Drivers/power-GBAPi

It only dosen't work when it is in the poweroff state, in all other cases the device is correctly connected and can write and read